# What does isinstance mean combined with ScalarNode, SequenceNode, and MappingNode?

Tags: python, yaml

I have googled without success so I would like what does `isinstance` means *combined* with yaml ScalarNode, SequenceNode and MappingNode?
(I know already what `isinstance` is)

For example

```
if isinstance(v,yaml.ScalarNode):
  #do something
elif isinstance(v,yaml.SequenceNode):
  #something else
elif isinstance(v, yaml.MappingNode):
  #another thing
```

Comment: If you know what *isinstance* means, what is unclear about the above code? It asks whether *v* is an instance of `yaml.ScalarNode`, `yaml.SequenceNode` or `yaml.MappingNode` respectively.  I assume your actual question is a different one, but you don't provide enough context to infer what it might be.

Comment: so ScalarNode is a type? What kind of type? There is so little info about these

Comment: [See here](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/blob/master/lib3/yaml/nodes.py#L25). So your actual question is *what are the semantics of these types* and not about `isinstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node types are a part of YAML's *Representation* data structure. YAML defines its (de)serialization pipeline as follows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaml.org](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/overview2.png))</sub>

The *Representation* is a, potentially cyclic, graph of nodes. In it, anchors and aliases have been resolved. In PyYAML, you typically use subgraphs of this data structure to implement custom constructors and representers that generate your native objects, as indicated by the arrows in the diagram.

A *ScalarNode* is a node representing a single scalar in the YAML source or output. A single scalar can be a plain scalar (e.g. `foo`), a quoted scalar (`'foo'` or `"foo"`), or a block scalar (starting with `|` or `>`). The scalar content, with escape sequences, newlines, indentation already processed, is available in the field `.value` as string. This is even true for values that are by default constructed into non-strings. For example, `true` will by default generate a boolean value, but as ScalarNode, it contains the value `"true"` as string.

*SequenceNode* is a node representing a sequence. The `value` field of a `SequenceNode` contains a list of nodes that correspond to the items in the sequence.

*MappingNode* is a node representing a mapping. The `value` field of a `MappingNode` contains a list of tuples, where each tuple consists of the key node and the value node.

All nodes have a field `tag` that contains the resolved tag of the node. i.e. a `ScalarNode` with value `true` would typically have the tag `yaml.org,2002:bool`. The resolved tag depends on the loader you use, for example if you use PyYAML's `BaseLoader`, `true` will resolve to a normal string, which is `yaml.org,2002:str`. In any case, if there was an explicit tag on the node (e.g. `!!str`, that tag will be in the `tag` field.

---

Coming back to the question, this kind of code is typically used in custom constructors. They get a node as input and are to produce a native value and return it. Usually, a custom constructor expects a specific kind of node but if you want to do proper error reporting, you still want to check whether you actually got the kind of node you need. For this, you use the code you posted.

Comment: This is very interesting. Is there a place where I can learn more about this, with example if possible?

Comment: @KansaiRobot I know this from a) reading the YAML specification (especially [chapter 3](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Processing) ) and b) reading the PyYAML source code. The spec is vital in understanding how most things work *in principle*, and PyYAML's docs are sadly lacking of a description of the low-level APIs but if you know how everything's *supposed* to work, you only need to figure out implementation details.